# Equivalence of Continuous Monotonic Functions $[0, 1] \to [0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, alternative-proof, curves

A couple of later clarifications to my original post ...

1. the monotonic non-decreasing functions mapping $[0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ are **surjective** - it appears from the comments that this was misunderstood.
2. Prof. Raussen has kindly assisted me in understanding the proofs in the paper, and I will at some point post an answer giving the proof. In outline, the result depends on three others......
   a) Given a countable set of points in [0, 1] - "stop values" - one can construct an element of $\mathscr M$ with non-trivial (closed) intervals - "stop intervals" - that map to these points.
   b) an element of $\mathscr M$ has at most countably many stop values.
   c) If the stop values of $\phi \subset $ stop values of $\eta$ then there is $\psi$ such that $\eta = \phi \circ \psi$ (all functions being elements of $\mathscr M$).

---

Let $\mathscr M$ be the set of continuous monotonic non-decreasing functions mapping $[0, 1] \to [0, 1]$.
Then under the operation of composition $\mathscr M$ is a monoid - a group without inverse: it is easily seen that it is closed, associative and has an identity ($i: [0, 1] \to [0, 1], i(t) = t$).
One also sees that all such functions are surjective (e.g. intermediate value theorem).

In the paper "Reparametrizations of continuous paths - Ulrich Fahrenberg and Martin Raussen" https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.3560.pdf it seems to be proven that given any $f, g \in \mathscr M$ there are $\mu, \nu \in \mathscr M$  such that $f \circ \mu = g \circ \nu$. I must admit the paper is a little beyond me, and **I'm looking for a simple proof for this**.

---

**Background.**

The paper shows among other things that re-parameterisation of paths is an equivalence relation, which then formalizes the definition of a curve as an equivalence class of paths. Showing symmetry and reflexivity is easy - the proof above is needed to show transitivity.

(The paper also shows that every path is equivalent to a regular path - i.e. one which does not "stop" at any point. An alternate proof for this can be found here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3317511.)

Comment: How is composition defined? By pointwise multiplication?

Comment: @PaulFrost No, (though this would also give a Monoid I think)  it's defined by  $f \circ g (x) = f(g(x))$

Comment: just an idea that I would think might work but didn't verify the details. Let $h=\max\{f\circ g,\ g\circ f\}$ and then try to find $\mu,\nu$ such that $f\circ\mu=h$ and  $g\circ\nu=h$.

Comment: I see that the requirement that the functions in $\mathcal M$ are continuous is essential. Without it one get the following cheap "solution" (assuming all functions involved map $0$ to $0$ and $1$ to $1$). Let $\lambda$ be any monotone non-decreasing function on $[0,1]$ with $\lambda(0)=0$, $\lambda(1)=1$, and $\lambda([0,1])=\{0,1\}$ (i.e. $\lambda$ is taking on only the values $0$ and $1$). Such a $\lambda$ could be described as the characteristic function of either some $(x,1],0\le x<1$ or some $[x,1],0<x\le1$. Then $f\circ\lambda=\lambda=g\circ\lambda$. Monotone *onto* implies continuous.

Comment: Perhaps one may involve integrals, say $h=\max\{f\circ g,g\circ f,f,g\}$ (or something like this), let $H(x)=\int_0^x h(x)dx$, similarly $F(x)=\int_0^x f(x)dx$ and $G(x)=\int_0^x g(x)dx$, was thinking of defining $\mu$ as some kind of "difference" of the derivatives of $H$ and $F$, but I need to think if I could clarify what I say and if it makes sense. Something along the lines $\int f(u)du=\int f(\mu(x))\mu'(x)dx$ where $u=\mu(x)$, try to define $\mu'(x)$ first.

Comment: Why are constant functions surjective?

Comment: The theorem fails for any two different constant functions. Also, if the sets of values of the two functions are disjoint (i.e. the max of one is less than the min of the other one).

Comment: When the sets of values are the same than the theorem seems to admit a proof in two elementary steps: (i) a reduction to homeomorphisms (ii) the homeomorphic case.

Comment: It's better to assume that $\ \mu\ \nu\ $ are non-constant or else the problem gets trivial.

Comment: The group of positively oriented homeomorphisms of $\ [0;1]\ $ was thoroughly studied in a paper from about 1960 or even much earlier. I think that it presented/characterized the whole group structure.

Comment: @WlodAA Thanks for your interest - please see my clarifications at the start of the question. And, do you have a link for the paper you mention ?

Comment: Tom, the appearances of word "surjective" in your text is still confusing. Indeed, a function $\ f:[0;1]\rightarrow[0;1]\ $ is surjective iff $\ \forall_{y\in[0;1]}\exists_{x\in[0;1]} f(x)=y.\ $

Comment: Tom, I don't have the reference to the paper which I saw in 1961 when I solved a problem about the orientation-preserving homeomorphisms of $\ [0;1],\ $ This problem was considered to be open until someone presented me with a paper which was much more extensive. The basic idea is rather simple and elementary. On the other hand, I I've discovered at that time that a similar problem, about the square root w.r. to function composition had a negative answer which (as specialized told me) had an instant application to the functional analysis, for the algebra of $\ C(S)\ $ over the circle $\ S.$

Comment: @WlodAA The functions under consideration are "re-parameterisations". $f \in \mathscr M$ is a continuous non-decreasing function with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$ and it follows from continuity that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: @Mirko Thanks for your feedback. I added some notes that may interest you.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few lemmas that appear to provide an answer. Not so, on a second reading, Lemma 2 is not valid..so my answer is simple, but perhaps way too simple.

Lemma 1. Suppose that $\psi$ is a monotonic non-decreasing function mapping $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$. 
Then $\psi$ is continuous.

Lemma 2. Suppose that $f,h\in\mathscr M$ and let 
$\mu(x)=\sup f^{-1}([0,h(x)])$. Then $\mu$ is a monotonic non-decreasing function mapping $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$ (and hence $\mu$ is also continuous), 
and $h(x)=f(\mu(x))$, that is $h=f\circ\mu$.

Lemma 3. Suppose that $f,g\in\mathscr M$ and let $h=g\circ f$. Then take $\nu=f$, and $\mu$ as in Lemma 2. We have $f\circ\mu=h=g\circ\nu$.

Reason why Lemma 2 is not valid. Suppose that for some $x$ we have that $f^{-1}(h(x))=[a,b]$ for some $a<b$. Then $\mu(x)=b$ (as defined in Lemma 2) and $\mu^{-1}(t)=\emptyset$ if $a<t<b$, so $\mu$ is not onto, and is not continuous. This seems to suggest that my approach letting $\nu=f$ is way too simplistic and won't work, and that a better definition of $\nu$ should take into account non-degenerate intervals on which $f$ is constant. I may think about this later, will leave this answer as is for now.

Comment: Can you get some mileage from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3317511 by first converting $f, g$ to strictly increasing functions ?

Comment: @TomCollinge Lemma 2 is valid for strictly increasing $f$ (homeo),and perhaps converting to strictly increasing $f,g$ might help,but it seems to me that if $f$ is constant on some interval then $f\circ\mu$ will be constant on some (other) interval depending on $\mu$, and (perhaps the only way) to counteract that is to make $\nu$ constant (on a suitable interval), and without reading in detail either the linked questions/answers or the paper you study, my louse guess is that the paper by F&R just takes care of possible complications (and perhaps there is no way to avoid that, but I do not know)

Comment: I think that https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3317511 fixes your problem here. $f, g$ can be composed with $\alpha, \beta \in \mathscr M $ so that $ \bar g = g \circ \alpha$ and $\bar f = f \circ \beta$ are strictly increasing  $\in \mathscr M$ . They then become invertible and the inverses also $\in \mathscr M$. Then $ \bar g = g \circ \beta = ( \bar f \circ \bar f^{-1}) \circ \bar g  = f \circ (\alpha \circ \bar f^{-1} \circ g \circ \beta)$. So $\mu = \beta$ and $\nu = \alpha \circ \bar f^{-1} \circ g \circ \beta$ ?

Comment: @TomCollinge I was thinking of this (or of something related, I guess), but had discarded it as an approach that won't work. Isn't the following correct? Say, $f^{-1}(c)=[a,b]$ where $a<b$. Given $\beta\in\mathscr M$, we have $(f\circ\beta)^{-1}(c)=\beta^{-1}(f^{-1}(c))=\beta^{-1}([a,b])$, and the latter preimage must contain a non-degenerate interval, showing that $f\circ\beta$ cannot be strictly increasing. P.S. I have yet to read in detail the question/answer that you cite, to see where is the contradiction, if any.

Comment: I'll be interested in your view after reading it. It also suggests an alternate approach with an integral.

Comment: @TomCollinge The answer you cite approximates $f$ with strictly increasing functions (as far as I read it), but I don't think they discuss compositions over there. The way I imagine that, first we replace $f$ with $(1-p)f$, some small $p>0$ (that is, smash that graph of $f$ a little bit), then we replace each horizontal interval on the graph of $(1-p)f$ with a line segment of a small positive slope, so that in total we gain exactly $p$, and the resulting function has a value $1$ at $1$ again. The total length of all intervals on which $f$ is constant, total is finite, so doing that is possible

Comment: @TomCollinge Your question there does indeed talk about composition. My reading of the answer there is superficial, and I can't really comment on the answer (so my previous comment may have to be ignored), but at any rate, what you state there is that $p = q \circ \phi$ where $q$ is regular. It doesn't say that $p$ is regular. So, yours two comments above, $\bar f = f \circ \beta$, all you could say given $f$ is that there is a regular (strictly increasing) $\bar f$ such that $f = \bar f \circ \beta$, not necessarily that $\bar f = f \circ \beta$.

Comment: True - I missed that.