# Topology: What Defines (non-Trivial) Paths as being the Same Trace (Curve)?

Tags: general-topology, curves

(In the absence of feedback on this site I've also posted the question at https://mathoverflow.net/q/343762)
I think I know the answer but can't prove it.

Assume that Y is a Hausdorff space and firstly that $p, q$ are simple (= continuous, injective) paths mapping $I = [0, 1] \to Y$. The idea that they represent the same trace or curve at least requires that that the images $p(I) = q(I)$   and that $p(0) = q(0) = y_1; p(1) = q(1) = y_2$
Then it follows that $p, q$ are homeomorphisms onto $p(I) = q(I)$, that there exists $\phi: I \to I$ defined by $\phi(x) = q^{-1}(p(x))$, a homeomorphism,  and then $p = q \circ \phi$.

If $p, q$ are not simple, then they are not injective and the above argument fails. They are however equivalent to regular paths (see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3317511 ), i.e. paths which are not constant on any non-trivial closed interval but which may self-intersect. So, if I could answer the question for regular paths that would do it.
It isn't immediately obvious what would define regular paths $p, q$  as being the same curve. One could define them to be the same based on the existence of $\phi$ as above, which clearly encompasses the simple case, but this is not intuitively satisfying.

I would like to show that a definition along the lines that they represent the same curve if they map $I$ to the same points in Y in the same sequence leads to an if and only if condition for the existence of $\phi$. If the curve has a finite number of self-intersections I can envisage this would follow by considering it as piece-wise simple, but what of the more general case ?

To formailise the concept of representing the same points in the same sequence one might require a bijection between their graphs $\psi: \{ (s, p(s)) \} \to \{ (t, q(t)) \}$ , though I don't see how to enforce sequence with this, and haven't seen it result in the necessary $\phi$.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

---

A later note....

In the case of two simple paths $p, q$ where there is a clearly defined bijection $\phi$,   one can define having the "same points in the same sequence" saying that for two points $y_a = p(s_a), y_b = p(s_b)$ with $s_b > s_a$ then $y_a = q(\phi(s_a)), y_b = q(\phi(s_b))$ and $\phi(s_b) > \phi(s_a)$.
The most I can find to say in the general case is that given $y_a = p(s_a), y_b = p(s_b)$ with $s_b > s_a$ then there exist (at least) a pair $t_a, t_b$ with $y_a = q(t_a), y_b = q(t_b)$ and $t_b > t_a$. Given that the paths can pass through points repeatedly, there could also be $t_{b2} < t_{a2}$ with  $y_a = q(t_{a2}), y_b = q(t_{b2})$.
In a more geometrical sense, two paths would have the "same points in the same sequence" if they trace the same curve in space - start and end points, direction, and repeating loops and intersections the same number of times.
Clearly the existence of such a function $\phi$ is a sufficient condition to then call two paths the same, but is it necessary, i.e. can its existence be inferred from preservation of sequence ?

Comment: What do you mean when you refer to the "same points in the same sequence"? Can you clarify this? Do you mean that $p(I)=q(I)$, and if $t_1 < t_2$, and $u_1,u_2$ are such that $q(u_i)=t_i$, then $u_1<u_2$? Or just that if $t_1<t_2$, then there exist $u_1,u_2$ such that $q(u_i)=t_i$ and $u_1<u_2$? Basically, what does "sequence" mean here?

Comment: Suppose $p(t) = (\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t)$ for $t \in I = [0,1]$, and $q_1(t) = (\cos 4\pi t, \sin 4\pi t)$; $q_2(t) = (\cos 2\pi t, -\sin 2\pi t)$; $q_3(t) = (\cos 2\pi\phi(t), \sin 2\pi\phi(t))$, where $\phi(t) = 4t(t-1/2)^2$. Now $q_1(I)=q_2(I)=q_3(I)=p(I)=$ the unit circle. But $q_1$ goes around twice, $q_2$ goes backwards, and $q_3$ backs up partly before completing the circle. So they all trace the same curve. Would you consider them to have the same points in the same sequence?

Comment: A bijection between graphs, with no other restriction, won't do much for you. The graphs are uncountable and bijective to the domain $I$, via the bijections $(s,p(s)) \leftrightarrow s$, or $(t,q(t)) \leftrightarrow t$. So they are bijective to each other.

Comment: @ZachTeitler. Thanks for feedback. I added some clarification of my meaning.

Comment: @ZachTeitler I might have found an answer - I'd be pleased to have your view. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p, q:I \to X$ be two **regular paths**, i.e. the functions are not constant on any non-trivial closed interval but may self-intersect any (even uncountable) number of times. 
While the points in their images are not necessarily unique, the points in their graphs are and in fact are identifiable by the domain value. In other words there are bijections
$\psi_p: I \to \mathscr \Gamma_p = \{(s, p(s)): s \in I\}$ given by $\psi_p(s) = (s, p(s))$ and
$\psi_q: I \to \mathscr \Gamma_q = \{(t, q(t)): t \in I\}$ given by $\psi_q(t) = (t, q(t))$.

To formalize the idea that $p, q$ represent the same points of a curve, extend the idea of a simple (injective) path (that they have the same image) to say instead that the same points in the image occur the same (perhaps uncountable) number of times, i.e. that there is a bijection
$\phi: \Gamma_p \to \Gamma_q$ such that $\phi((s, p(s))) = (t, q(t))$ with $p(s) = q(t)$.
Here, the reason for considering regular paths becomes apparent. For if $x_0 \in X$ and $p^{-1}(x_0)$ is a non-trivial interval $[a, b]$ while $q^{-1}(x_0) = c$, a single point, then no such bijection is possible.
(But $p^{-1}(x_0)$  and $q^{-1}(x_0)$ could be an equal (even infinite) number of points).

Then $\pi = \psi_q^{-1} \circ \phi \circ \psi_p: I \to I$ is a bijection.
There are of course any number of bijections $I \to I$, but this is one with the property that
$\pi(s) = \psi_q^{-1} \circ \phi \circ \psi_p(s) $ .......**(A)**
$ = \psi_q^{-1} \circ \phi (s, p(s))$
$ = \psi_q^{-1} (t, q(t))$ with $q(t)  = p(s)$ by the property of $\phi$
$= t$ with $q(t)  = p(s)$
I.e. $p(s) = q(\pi(s))$

Now consider the ordering of the points and formalize this by saying that the points in the graph inherit the order of their domain value. E.g. the order of points in $\Gamma_p =  \{(s, p(s)): s \in I\}$ corresponds to $s$ so $s_2 > s_1 \iff $  $(s_2, p(s_2))$ is after $(s_1, p(s_1))$.

Then to say that the points in $\Gamma_q$ are in the same order requires that among bijections $\Gamma_p \to \Gamma_q$   we can choose a $\phi$ such that
$s_2 > s_1 \iff (s_2, p(s_2)) > (s_1, p(s_1)) \iff \phi((s_2, p(s_2)) ) > \phi((s_1, p(s_1))) $.

From (A) we have $\pi(s) = \psi_q^{-1} \circ \phi \circ \psi_p(s) $ so that $\psi_q \circ\pi \circ \psi_p^{-1} =  \phi  $, and then
$\phi((s, p(s)) ) =  \psi_q \circ\pi \circ \psi_p^{-1}((s, p(s)) ) = \psi_q \circ\pi (s) =(\pi (s), q(\pi (s)))  $

So, $s_2 > s_1 \iff (s_2, p(s_2)) > (s_1, p(s_1)) \iff \phi((s_2, p(s_2)) ) > \phi((s_1, p(s_1))) $. 
$\iff (\pi (s_2), q(\pi (s_2))) > (\pi (s_1), q(\pi (s_1))) \iff \pi (s_2) > \pi (s_1)$
I.e. $s_2 > s_1 \iff \pi (s_2) > \pi (s_1)$  .

**So if two regular paths $p, q$ represent the same points the same number of times in the same sequence, there exists $\pi; I \to I $ a strictly increasing bijection and therefore continuous and therefore a homeomorphism and $p(s) = q(\pi(s))$.**

Comment: It sounds good to me! In the end it seems like it is pretty much the idea that Andreas Blass suggested on MathOverflow. But it sounds like you have traced through from a starting point that is natural for you, to see why that final idea turns out to be the right one--not just a kind of arbitrary made-up thing. Does that sound fair?

Comment: @ZachTeitler I think so. Thanks for feedback. This is part of a sequence of proofs to show (from a natural starting point) the a "curve" can be seen topologically (without metrics or lengths) as an equivalence class of paths $p = q $ when there are continuous surjective non-decreasing functions $\eta_p, \eta_q: I \to I$ such that $p \circ \eta_p = q \circ \eta_q$. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3320826 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3317511

Comment: I see no real difference with Andreas Blass's suggestion mentioned above, but your way of phrasing it does explain why Andreas' suggestion is a very natural one. Why I see no difference is this: if there is a bijection   
$\phi: \Gamma_p \to \Gamma_q$ such that $\phi((s, p(s))) = (t, q(t))$ with $p(s) = q(t)$, then $\phi'$ (the first-coordinate 'projection' of $\phi$) is a bijection from $[0,1]$ to itself such that $q\circ\phi'=p$. I would personally like to also see a characterization along the lines of my answer on MO (with proof of validity :-) ). Good work though, cheers Franka